# Send SSL certificate in javascript GET query

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to send a SSL certificate got from a textbox/textarea to a https GET query?

I need to make a GET to a server to get a json file and it needs to use SSL certificates in this way.

Server is made in node.js, I don't know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the target address and the server at that address is setup to use https the javascript get will be encrypted automaticly. Theres is nothing done manually in javascript whatsoever